# List<Super Class> which contains objects of different subclasses

Tags: java

Now I have a class Animal, with three subclasses extending it: Dog, Cat, and Fish.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark(){}
}
```

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    public void catchMouse(){}
}
```

```
class Fish extends Animal {
    public void swim(){}
}
```

And I have a list:

```
List<Animal> listOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I use a static method to add objects of Dog, Cat and Fish to the list:

```
public static void addAnimal(List<Animal> list, AnimalInfo info) {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    switch (info) {
        case 0:
            animal = new Dog();
            break;
        case 1:
            animal = new Cat();
            break;
        case 2:
            animal = new Fish();
            break;
    }
    list.add(animal);
}
```

I call this static method 3 times and add a Dog object, a Cat object and a Fish object to the list in order. Now the list should contain a Dog instance, a Cat instance and a Fish instance.

Now I want to call bark() on the Dog instance:

```
list.get(0).bark();
```

But this will not work obviously.

What is the best way to achieve this? Use:

```
(Dog)(list.get(0)).bark();
```

？

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. If you don't know whether it's a `Dog` or not you can check with `animal instanceof Dog`.

Comment: You seem to be approaching this incorrectly... You have a list of `Animal` and you're assuming position 0 is a Dog ? The textbook example has `Animal.makeNoise()`. `Dog` will override `makeNoise()` and make it "bark". `Cat` will override and make it "meow" etc. The whole point is so you don't have to make assumptions about which animal is where in the list.

Comment: In my design makeNoise() is not elegant, I want to check the type of the objects in the list when I get them. Then does it seem that using ```instanceof()``` is the most common way?

Comment: @Cyan you're probably asking the wrong question. What are you trying to do that standard OO techniques are not elegant?

Comment: I mean in my design, not all animals can makeNoise().

Comment: So in the animals that don't make a noise, `makeNoise()` does nothing (aka silence). The whole point is you shouldn't be saying "is it a dog ? yes? then bark() else is it a cat? yes? then meow() else is it a rhinoceros ? ..." - that completely defeats the purpose of OO.

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense.

Comment: That or you can add an abstract method in the `Animal` class `bool canMakeNoise()` to call before attempting `makeNoise()`

Answer (score 3):

I think utilizing inheritance here could be a good approach in this case, but I thought I'd share an alternative.

Another approach here is to use the visitor pattern.  This is especially good when you don't know what you need to do with an object when you declare its class, or if you have contextual behaviour (such as updating another object's state) that you want to keep separate from your Animal classes (Separation of Concerns)

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor);
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    void bark() { ... }

    @Override
    void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    void meow() { ... }

    @Override
    void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visit(Dog dog);
    void visit(Cat cat);
}

// Somewhere else...

AnimalVisitor voiceVisitor = new AnimalVisitor() {
    @Override
    void visit(Dog dog) {
        dog.bark();
    }

    @Override
    void visit(Cat cat) {
        cat.meow();
    }
}

animalList.get(0).accept(voiceVisitor);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to achieve this?

If you use List of Animals you should use Animal-only methods further in program logick.
The idea of List is that you iterating over it any apply the same to items.
Make:

```
 class Animal {
      public void voice(){}
      public void swim(){}
    }

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void voice(){
          print('bark')}

}
class Cat extends Animal {
    public void voice(){
          print('meow')}
}
```

And if you do want to have a list of all animals, they just do noting, instead of calling is instance of what is more expencive

Comment: or even keep `Dog.bark()` but call it from `voice()` instead of trying to call it directly.

Comment: keep if you want to have unesesary method call

Comment: Thus does it mean that it is a common way in OO design to keep voice() and swim() in Animal though some subclasses can not voice() or swim()?

Comment: a common way in OO is Lipskow (?) substitution prinzip what means subclasses must be able do what parent is able to do, and act in the same way as the parent. The hierarchy here would be like Animal -> (SwimmingAnimal , NotSwimmingAnimal); NotSwimmingAnimal ->(MouseCatcher, Barker) and have list of SwimmingAnimal, whatever. Or you can do visitor

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is through interface

```
    interface IAnimal {
    public void Roar();
    public void Swim();
}

class Animal implements IAnimal{

    @Override
    public void Roar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("IROAR");
    }

    @Override
    public void Swim() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!(this instanceof Lion)) {

            System.out.println("ISWIM");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("this animal cannot swim");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I added a check for Lion instance for Swim() method since not all animals can swim.

Client Code:

```
    List<IAnimal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    animals.add(new Lion());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.get(0).Swim();
    animals.get(1).Roar();
```

Comment: This looks like a violation of the Open-Closed principle.  For example, if I add a new subclass Camel (apparently unable to swim) then I need to alter my base class to make sure no one tries to throw it into water.

Comment: You're right. I was just letting OP know other ways of doing it and getting rid of the annoying casts. Of course this is not the right object oriented design approach for his particular case.